# How can I print the vocabulary name instead of the referenced term in a node template?

Tags: 8, theming, taxonomy-terms

Let's say I have a content type article with a field "taxonomy".

The vocabulary is "fruits".

The terms are "apple", "orange", "bananas"

The article belongs to "orange".

I can easily print in my twig template the term of the article :

```
{{ content.field_taxo_fruit }}
```

Result is "orange".

But I don't find an easy way to print the vocabulary : "fruits".

On an other project, I used `views field` and I used "rewrite result". But here, I use twig template like `node--article--teaser.html.twig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)'s submodule Kint, and then in your template print `{{ kint() }}` to get a pretty-printed dump of all available variables.

Unfortunately I couldn't find the vocabulary label/name in there. Only the field label:

```
{{ content.field_taxo_fruit['#title'] }}
```

@4k4's answer below only prints the vocabulary's machine name. But not the label/name. But I finally got hold of the vocabulary name in a preprocess function in `MYTHEME.theme` from where I sent it over to Twig:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node__article(&$variables) {

  $node = $variables['node'];

  $vid = array_values($node->field_taxo_fruit->getSettings()['handler_settings']['target_bundles'])[0];

  $vocabulary = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_vocabulary')->load($vid);

  $variables['taxo_fruit_vocab'] = $vocabulary->label();
}
```

And in `node--article.html.twig` then it's:

```
{% if taxo_fruit_vocab %}
  <div class="taxo-fruit-vocab">
    Vocab: {{ taxo_fruit_vocab }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: +1, your approach is what you should try first before digging into the field object like i've tried in my answer.

Comment: Perfect, I always try first with admin UI but I hadn't thought of "the label solution".

Comment: @4k4 I found this interesting : It works but it is not really the taxonomy vocabulary name which is printed but the field name (entity reference field). Am I right ?

Comment: @SébastienGicquel – Yes indeed. I only noticed it too late. Wait a minute, I'm already looking the vocabulary up. Unfortunately 4k4's solution didn't printed it for me.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel – Answer updated. Sorry for misdirecting you initially.

Comment: No worries, thanks for answering so quickly. @4k4 solution is working partially in my project, it prints the sanitized name of vocabulary (Notice the `node.xxx`Instead of `content.xxx` in his answer) I will try your solution and send you a feed back.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel – 4k4 updated their answer on how to achieve that from just the template. You should accept their answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

The vocabulary machine name is the bundle ID of the term, which you can get through the node object:

```
{{ node.field_taxo.entity.bundle }}
```

To load the label of the vocabulary:

```
{{ node.field_taxo.entity.vid.entity.label }}
```

This works only when the field has content. For an empty field you would have to dig into the field definition you get from the same field object and check whether the field is restricted to a single target bundle.

Comment: Ah yeah! Unfortunately it only prints the vid, not the label.

Comment: @leymannx, you can load the label in Twig too, because the term references the bundle config entity. I add this to the answer.

Comment: You are genius. But from where do you know this? Is it basically just the same pattern for every entity? Or did you dig really deep in what `{{ kint() }}` returned you? I asked OP to accept your answer instead.

Comment: @leymannx, this pattern is the same for any content entity with bundles. BTW I think both answers are valid, mine is more literal, yours considering the overall context, although it would need some clarification, machine name (fruits looks like one) or label, vocabulary from the content or field config.